Why is VSCode displaying logical operators as specified, but not conditional operators?
I've been modifying the rpg.tmLanguage.json and settings.json files for my VSCode install to set syntax coloring to my preference. I've been able to get most my changes to work, but am having problems with operators. Specifically, I've not been able to get conditional operators to change color. I've checked them with the Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope tool, and the comparison operators (red box in image) are defaulting to the color set by the lowest level, source.rpg (which is set to #00FF00).
(https://i.sstatic.net/hSigN.png)
I know certain characters have to be escaped due to json, but the logical operators are not in that group. I tried escaping them anyway by prefixing "\\", but that didn't make a difference. I also tested with a regex validator (regex101.com), and it reported the same thing; words 'and' and 'not' get selected, but not the comparison operators. What am I missing? Any assistance would be appreciated.

\b matches on the boundary between word and non-word characters.  For something like and, surrounded by spaces, such boundaries exist at both ends of the string.  But <> contains no word characters, so there is no boundary.
